# Fuzzy Logic Duplicate Name Detector

Tags: javascript, fuzzy-search, fuzzy-logic, fuzzy-comparison

I am working on an application with large number of products and brands.
We need to match brand names and identify duplicates (possibly mis-typed) and merge them.
Something similar to what Android does for contacts.

I have seen some solutions using the database distance functions.
Can anyone suggest any JavaScript libraries that may help me achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Brand names aren't (hopefully very long). This [Fuse](http://kiro.me/projects/fuse.html) library works well.
It's as simple as:

```
var fue = new Fuse(json_array_of_objects, object_with_keys_to_retrive);
var rslt = fuse.search('YourString');
```

The other alternative is: [FuzzySet.js](http://glench.github.io/fuzzyset.js/)